# GCP Dataflow Changing Date Format Causing Errors/Retries

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-datastream

Replicating a mysql db using cloud_datastream_to_bigquery template in dataflow. So mysql->datastream->gcs->dataflow->bigquery

I'm seeing this in my DLQ/retry
"error_message":{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"estimated_delivery_date","message":"Invalid date: '2023-07-26Z'","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}}

When I look at what datastream is putting into the GCS bucket, "ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE":"2023-07-26T00:00:00.000Z". This stream has been running for months until today when a handful of different date fields starting causing a ton of retries and worker spikes. I would love any input, thanks!

I've been using a UDF to fix each date individually, but there has to be a root cause of this. Thanks again for looking. I expected the error to be on an individual field. I keep finding more. The owners of the source mysql db say that nothing has changed.

Comment: The input data seems to be a timestamp rather than data. What about changing BigQuery types from data to timestamp? Bear in mind, that changing BQ tables types may cause the entire table to delete, so backup your data before.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The data type is determined by datastream pulling from the source database schema then used by dataflow to create the log and replica tables. I manually tried to change the fields to STRING, but that killed the mapping. The value YYYY-MM-DDZ is not valid for timestamp or date as far as i can tell.